# magento media manager full url

Tags: magento

I'am using a built in Magento Filebrowser on my extension to magento.
I have this problem. If i open a magento File browser, then select file and then click button "Insert File"
Then Filebrowser gives me a url what looks like this _directive/e3ttZWRpYSB1cmw9Ind5c2l3eWcvc2VhcmNoLnBuZyJ9fQ,,/key/dc3e70661f817703710378d51351495b/">http://www.infira.ee/magento/index.php/admin/cms_wysiwyg/directive/_directive/e3ttZWRpYSB1cmw9Ind5c2l3eWcvc2VhcmNoLnBuZyJ9fQ,,/key/dc3e70661f817703710378d51351495b/

how do i convert this url to normal full image url some thing like this http://www.infira.ee/magento/dir/dir/dir/someImage.png.
I need it cause this full url gos to the css file.

Comment: have you managed to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Login to Admin.

Go to System > Configuration > Content Management (Under General) > WYSIWYG Options

'Use Static URLs for Media Content in WYSIWYG for Catalog' - Select "Yes"